# Is there a way to adjust the font-size to fit a fixed box without using css overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

`<div style="width : 50px"></div>`

When the number of letters increases and leaves the area,
Is there a way to automatically reduce the font size instead of css overflow?

Comment: Not sure - you might have to use javascript

Comment: [text-justify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-justify) might help. Also, welcome to StackOverflow, please review [ask] and provide a [mcve] when asking a question

Answer (score 5):

I found this question interesting, so I'll provide a simple JavaScript example in case it helps somebody.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const span = document.querySelector('span');


createDynamicTextbox(div, span);


function createDynamicTextbox(outer, inner) {
  if (!outer.style.fontSize) outer.style.fontSize = outer.clientHeight;
  const initialSize = +outer.style.fontSize.match(/\d+/)[0];

  inner.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    let [n, unit] = outer.style.fontSize.split(/(?<![a-z])(?=[a-z]+)/);
    n=+n;

    while (outer.offsetWidth > inner.offsetWidth) {
      n++;
      outer.style.fontSize = n+unit;
      if (n >= initialSize) return;
    }

    while (inner.offsetWidth > outer.offsetWidth) {
      n--;
      outer.style.fontSize = n+unit;
      if (n <= 0) return;
    }
  });

  inner.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input'));
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 30px"><span contenteditable>Edit Me</span></div>
```